# Loop through my table's specific column

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

html

```
<table id="myList">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <td>Product ID</td>
                   <td>Product Name</td>
                   <td>Quantity</td>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>

           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Javascript

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

       var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

       var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

       var otherCell = newRow.insertCell(2);

       var check;
       var myText = result.text;
       var myTextTwo =  myText.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
       alert(myTextTwo);

       for (var i = 0; i < tableRef.rows.length; i++) {

           if (myTextTwo != tableRef.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) {
               check = true
           }
           else if (myTextTwo == tableRef.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) {
               tableRef.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML += 1;
               check = false;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (check) {
           var newText = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
           var otherText = document.createTextNode("1");
           newCell.appendChild(newText);
           otherCell.appendChild(otherText);
       }
       else {
           alert("You have scanned this item before.");
       }
```

What I have done is scanning a QR that contains a Product ID(e.g. "123") and insert the Product ID into the column called "Product ID", which I am able to do it.

However, what I am trying to do now is to, if the user scan a QR code that contains the same Product ID(e.g. "123"), my code will be able to detect the duplicate and add onto the quantity.

So what I planned to do is to loop through "Product ID" column and check if there's any duplicate. If there isn't any duplicates, the Quantity for the Product ID would be 1.

```
Product ID | Product Name | Quantity
  123      |   Hello      |     1
```

Otherwise, duplicate exist, Quantity would be 2.

```
Product ID | Product Name | Quantity
  123      |   Hello      |     2
```

Comment: What value or object do you get on scanning?

Comment: Isn't `tableRef.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML` already getting you what you want?

Comment: You need to convert the `innerHTML` to a number before adding 1. Otherwise it will do string concatenation, so you'll get `11` instead of `2`.

Comment: I executed the code I had and I faced this error, 

IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'insertCell' on 'HTMLTableRowElement': The value provided (2) is outside the range [-1, 1].

Comment: If the table is initially empty, your loop will never run, so you'll never get to `check = true;`. You should initialize it to `true`, and then just set it to `false` when you find a match. You don't need the first `if` that looks for a non-match.

Comment: You can't insert cell 2 until after you insert cells 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. It worked!

Comment: If the product id is unique, you might consider adding id values to the rows, something like id='product' + productId (e.g. id='product123').  Then you can just do getElementById(...) instead of having to loop through.  For a small table it wouldn't make much difference but on a larger table the looping could get expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

// save the row number of the existing product
var found = false;
var myText = result.text;
var myTextTwo = myText.replace(/['"]+/g, '');

// search the table for the existing product
for (var i = 0; i < tableRef.rows.length && !found; ++i) {
  // if you found it then
  if (tableRef.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML == myTextTwo) {
    // update the value
    tableRef.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML += 1;

    // and say we found it
    found = true;
  }
}

// at this point, if we didn't find anything then add a new row
if (!found) {
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
  newRow.insertCell(0).innerText = "...";
  newRow.insertCell(0).innerText = "...";
  newRow.insertCell(0).innerText = 1;
}

<table id="myList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product ID</td>
      <td>Product Name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

The function `duplicateCell` returns the number of the row that contains a duplicate on the given column or `null` if no duplicate found.

The function `addOne` requires a product ID to check for duplicates, a product Name (if no duplicates are found, the product will need a name, otherwise it is ignored) and it also needs to know what table to work on.
AddOne looks for duplicates using the above function and adds one to the quantity.

I started with 1 car 1 bike and 1 skateboard, added 2 bike (id2) and added 2 rockets (id 4).

```js
var duplicateCell = function(tableId, columnNumber, stringToSearch) {
 var myTbody = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
 var tableRows = myTbody.rows.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < tableRows; i++) {
  if (myTbody.rows[i].cells[columnNumber].innerHTML.trim() == stringToSearch)
   return i
 }
 return null;
}

function addOne(productId, productName, tableId) {
 var myTbody = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
 var rowIndex = duplicateCell(tableId, 0, productId)
 if (rowIndex != null) {
  myTbody.rows[rowIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = +myTbody.rows[rowIndex].cells[2].innerHTML.trim() + 1;
 } else {
 var tableRows = myTbody.rows.length;
  var row = document.getElementById(tableId).insertRow();
  c1 = row.insertCell(0);
  c2 = row.insertCell(1);
  c3 = row.insertCell(2);
  c1.innerHTML = productId;
  c2.innerHTML = productName;
  c3.innerHTML = 1;
 }
}
addOne("4", "Rocket", "myList")
addOne("4", "Rocket", "myList")
addOne("2", " ", "myList")
```

```html
<table id="myList">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Product ID</td>
   <td>Product Name</td>
   <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1 </td>
   <td>Car </td>
   <td>1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2 </td>
   <td>Bike </td>
   <td>1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3 </td>
   <td>Skateboard </td>
   <td>1 </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```